# Ninject decorated class binding

Tags: c#, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

I want to bind decorated classes with Ninject.

```
public interface ICommandBus{ Send<T>(T command);}

// This is my first CommandBus class I will decorate this.

public class CommandBus: ICommandBus { 
    public void send(){ //handle commands... }
}
```

I have created a CommandBusDecorator

```
public abstract class CommandBusDecorator: ICommandBus
{
    private readonly ICommandBus commandBus;

    protected CommandBusDecorator(ICommandBus commandBus)
    {
        this.commandBus = commandBus;
    }

    public virtual void Send<T>(T command)
    {
        commandBus.SendCommand(command);
    }
}
```

And a decorated class to apply something.

```
public class DecoratedFirstCommandBus: CommandBusDecorator{ .... }
```

I want to bind the dependencies with Ninject but Ninject does not contain decorator implementation.

```
Kernel.Bind<ICommandBus>().To<CommandBusDecorator>();
Kernel.Bind<ICommandBus>().To<CommandBus>();
Kernel.Bind<ICommandBus>().To<CommandBus>()
            .WhenInjectedInto<DecoratedFirstCommandBus>();
```

But error occuring:

"ExceptionMessage": "An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'ValuesController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor."

Values controller takes only one constructor,

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    private ICommandBus commandBus;

    public ValuesController(ICommandBus commandBus)
    {
        this.commandBus = commandBus;
    }
}
```

If I use only one binding: `Kernel.Bind<ICommandBus>().To<CommandBus>();`
application is working.

Comment: r u using web api ? So the problem seems about the configuration of the dependency resolver, but can you show the `ctor` of the `ValuesController`?

Comment: This exception message only occurs when the default asp.net mvc dependency resolver is used. Ninject would throw different exceptions with other messages. So what's wrong is that you haven't properly set up ninject. There's already quite a lot of questions around regarding the same issue. Just search for the exception message and "ninject".